# CodeIgniter validation error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use CodeIgniters built in validation to validate my form however whenever I add

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

My html code breaks and nothing beyond this point comes up on the website, and my page source just closes off tags and thats all.

Heres my form code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<form action="myController/validate" method="post">

Username<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And my php code:

```
public function validation() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); //load the library for validation

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required'); // set rules, u can make it more complex

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('loginView'); //redirect to registe.php if there is any error
    } else {
        $data['msg'] = 'Your details been registered successfully';
        $this->load->view('login', $data); //if there is no error redirect to login.php with success message
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this could be the error?

Comment: Please, add more details, such as: html form output and controller code, where you run form validation.

Comment: Done, please ask if I am missing anything else just tried to make it as neat as possible

Comment: @jonijones Tried it, it doesn't seem to work again nothing appears, except now the form tags appear but that is all.

Comment: @Rooster is right, you need to check php error log, also see status of page loading in dev console or firebug. If you use local server, set ``error_reporting = E_ALL`` in ``php.ini``

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, I hadn't loaded it up on the autoload. If anyone else has the same issue, go to the autoload.php file and in your libraries add 'form_validation'.